# CSV file cannot be Found Exception - CSV Reader

Tags: java, csv, liferay

I'm using CSVReader for parsing a csv file from **LIFERAY REPO**.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath), ',', '"', 1);
         List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
         String listString = "";
         for(String[] row : allRows){
             for (String s : row)
             {
                 listString += s + ",";
             }
         }
```

Here, filePath is passed as a local path of file. However when I'm passing in path of **Liferay repo**, it is throwing me a `FileNotFoundException`. Should I add any property or something else? What am I missing here? Help?

Comment: Would it be possible to share the path or a mock up of it?

Comment: http://localhost:8182/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=f10e8db0-742  .. something of this sort

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) Java Tutorial, you need to use an `InputStream`. Maybe you could try with that and see how it goes?

Comment: Hey thanks @npinti . You just saved my life there bro. :)

Comment: Added as answer to make it easier for other to see. If you think more information should be provided, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answer for completeness sake.

As per [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) Java tutorial, files which are available through a URL need to be loaded through an `InputStream`. Using that should make the file available to the CSV parser.